# how to approach a multiplayer game facebook app project?

Tags: flash, facebook, google-app-engine, multiplayer

i wish to create a multiplayer game facebook app. a game will have  1 to 4 people in it playing from their own systems.

i wish to target, lets say, 10K simultaneous online users.

i am planning to write the client side game in Flash.

i wanted to know how these clients communicate with each other.

can these clients communicate directly with each other or i should go with "server as middleman" approach ? i want the game to work even in "restricted" networks.

if server, how do i have things working from google app engine cloud service ? 
i came across channel API, should i use that ? would it work with a flash client ?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on clients communicating directly with each other - with NAT this is difficult to impossible, not to mention browser sandboxing issues. Instead, communicate via the server. If you need asynchronous (server-triggered) communications then yes, you will need to use something like the channel API, or an external service like PubNub.

Regarding using the channel API in Flash, this isn't directly possible, but you could have a Javascript shim that receives Channel API messages and sends them to the flash app. Or, write your app in Javascript - HTML5 is the way forward!

Answer (score 1):

http://gaeswf.appspot.com/

> The GAE SWF Project is a resource of Flash and Flex-related knowledge specifically aimed at getting you up and running quickly with Google App Engine, a wonderful platform for building and deploying massively-scalable Flash and Flex applications.

Answer (score 1):

How exactly the communications should work depends on what exactly is happening in your game. In general though a Facebook game should have the players interacting through the server and not communicating with each other directly.

As for how to use Google App Engine, as mentioned the GAE SWF project is specifically designed for that.